# What's wrong with this usage of range?

Tags: syntax, go

I try to get a directory listing using this function:

```
package main;
import ("fmt"; "os"; "io/ioutil")

func main() {
    dir, _ := ioutil.ReadDir("..")
    var f os.FileInfo
    for f = range dir {
        fmt.Println(f.Name())
    }
}
```

According to the [documentation of ReadDir](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadDir), it should return `[]os.FileInfo` as the first return parameter. When I try to compile it, however, I get

```
cannot assign type int to f (type os.FileInfo) in range: int does not implement os.FileInfo (missing IsDir method)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
for _, f = range dir {
        fmt.Println(f.Name())
    }
```

You ignore the index and only assign the dir entry.

You don't have to declare the var if you don't want. This would also work:

```
func main() {
    dir, _ := ioutil.ReadDir("..")
    for _, f := range dir {
        fmt.Println(f.Name())
    }
}
```

Note the '`:=`' after '`_, f`', instead of your '`f =` '.

The issue doesn't comes from what `ReadDir()` returns, but comes from the `range` expression, which returns (index, value).
From the Go Specs "[For Statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)":

```
Range expression                          1st value          2nd value (if 2nd variable is present)

array or slice  a  [n]E, *[n]E, or []E    index    i  int    a[i]       E
```

Comment: Thanks! I know that I can omit the declaration, it's just to get a more explicit compiler error. It still eludes me why you'd put the index first in the return of a range. Isn't the whole point that you want to avoid iterating by index if possible?

Comment: @Tobias that could be a good question in itself. I suppose it follows the logic of composite literal (http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) where you find first the key or index, then the value(s)

Comment: Makes sense. But I'm afraid if I'm going to ask that question it's probably going to be closed as "Not programming related" or so...

Comment: @Tobias it depends how you present it ;) but in the end, adding '`_, `' in order to ignore the index part doesn't seem to be such an hassle in the first place.